# Display the product tag list with links in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tags, product

I would like to do the same thing as this code does, but for product tags in woocommerce:

```
<?php $tags = get_tags(); ?>
<div class="tags">
<?php foreach ( $tags as $tag ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ); ?> " rel="tag"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></a>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

I haven't found yet the way to do it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Woocommerce Product Tags are a custom taxonomy.

So you will use instead WordPress `get_terms()` and `get_term_link()` functions this way:

```
<?php $terms = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => 'product_tag', 'hide_empty' => false)); ?>
<div class="product-tags">
<?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term->term_id, 'product_tag' ); ?> " rel="tag"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Code is tested and works.

---

> **Note:** For product categories, the taxonomy is **`'product_cat'`** instead of `'product_tag'`…

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you. Would you happen to know a great link to some documentation so I can style this content on a page? I am trying to display the tag's description. Is there css code that will work for me to put the tags in a more organized manner (columns maybe)?

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying. Maybe I can clarify my question. What can I add to the code you share so that the tag's description is visible by 150 character summary? Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

To get the product tag description, add this code where you want it to appear:

```
<?php echo $term->description; ?>
```

For example, I wanted it to appear as a bullet list, with the description after each linked tag. Here's what I used:

```
<?php $terms = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => 'product_tag', 'hide_empty' => false)); ?>
<div class="product-tags">
<ul>
<?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term->term_id, 'product_tag' ); ?> " rel="tag"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>: <?php echo $term->description; ?> </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul></div>
```

Just change the HTML code and/or add some CSS classes, if you want to further customize it.